# how to give permission for Kivy android scripts?

Tags: android, kivy, pyjnius

I have installed kivy in my phone.

What Ia am trying to do is write a script from system and put it in /sdcard/kivy/myapp folder. How do I give permission to my script? eg Bluetooth need special permission to access it. Is there any way by which i could give permission in script for accessing Bluetooth? I came to know that I could give permission to apk but is there any way by which i could give permission in script?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to add pragmatically permission. The Kivy launcher is built with few permission by default (INTERNET and BLUETOOTH if i remember well). For your case, you'll need to build your own APK using [python-for-android](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer).

Comment: how hard would it be to compile Kivy Launcher with a new permission? In my case I'm interested in using it with BLUETOOTH_ADMIN. What steps would I need to take? I have Kivy installed on my OSX machine, though possibly not some other things that could be necessary.